# Getting images from a URL to a directory

Tags: image, url

Well, straight to the point, I want to put a URL, and get all the images inside this URL, for example

www.blablabla.com/images

in this images folder I want to get all the images... I already know how to get a image from an specific URL, but I dunno how to get all of the without having to go straight to the exactly path, is there a way to get a list of all the items inside a URL path or something like that?

Comment: If the images are on a website you could get the source code first, then extract the contents of the img src tag to get the image URLs

Comment: but what if they are inside a path and not in a HTML page?

Comment: This is moving into the realms of FTP instead of HTTP

Comment: I think you're going to have to use some kind of FTP process to grab a file listing and download the files (via FTP instead of URL). Take a look at [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) which has a FTP library

Comment: *"but I dunno how to get all"*  But I don't know why some people ask questions using slang that will not be understood by a part of the English as a 2nd (3rd, 4th..) language audience.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically, this can't be done. Well, not under normal circumstances anyway. The problem is that you don't know what files are in that directory.

...unless the server has "directory listing" on. This is considered a security vulnerability, so the chance this is the case isn't too high. (The idea is that you are exposing details about your server that you don't have to, and while it is no problem on its own, it might make things that can be a security problem known to the world.)

This means that if the server is yours, you can turn directory listing on, or that when the server happens to have it turned on, you can visit the url (www.blablabla.com/images) and see a listing of all the files in that directory. This doesn't always look exactly the same, but in general the common thing is that you will get an html page with links to all the files in the directory. As such, all you would need to do is retrieve the page and parse the links, ending up with the urls to the images you want.

If the server is yours, I would recommend at least looking into any other options you might have. One such option could be to make a script that provides all the urls instead of relying on directory listing. This does not have some of the more unfortunate implications that directory listing has (like showing non-images that happen to be in the same directory) and can be more flexible.

Another way to do this might be to use a protocol different from HTTP like FTP, SFTP or SCP. These protocols do not have the same flexibility as a script, but they do have even more safety as they easily allow you to restrict access to both the directory listing and your images to only people with correct login details (or private keys). (Of course, if such a protocol is available for your use and it's not your own server, you could use them as well.)

Comment: @ADTC, that's a good one (though only applicable when it's your own server)

Comment: *"...unless the server has "directory listing" on."*  I heard that was also considered a security vulnerability, though I don't know why.